# Prove that $y'=-y^3+\sin x $ has a unique solution satisfying $y(0)=y(2\pi)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that the ordinary differential equation
$$y'=-y^3+\sin x $$
has a unique solution satisfying $y(0)=y(2\pi)$

It's really hard for me to figure out the existence and the uniqueness.

I don't have any clue about this problem. Maybe we can let $u(x)=y(x+2\pi)-y(x)$, then $u(x)$ should satisfy $u(0)=0$ and some differential equations.

Comment: This is, up to a change in the time direction, a duplicate of [Solution to ODE $ x' = x^3+ \sin( t)$ and showing it has a periodic solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2970212/115115). After the change in the time direction, my answer there directly treats this problem.

Comment: A much earlier question for this ODE asking [Is this periodic solution unique? (ODE)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/638780/115115)