# prove that there is only one a, such: $y'(x)=y(x)^3+\sin(x);y(0)=a$ and y(x) is a unique periodic solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

prove that there is only one real a, such:
$y'(x)=y(x)^3+\sin(x);y(0)=a$  which satisfies that y is a unique periodic solution.
Find whether a is greater than 0 or smaller than 0.
I believe that this equation is not solvable.
I tried to get a contradiction of the existence of 2 solutions depending on a, but I found no such relationship as that.

Comment: Can you find anything in your notes surrounding this task that is different from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638780/is-this-periodic-solution-unique and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970212/solution-to-ode-x-x3-sin-t

Comment: @LutzLehmann this question is quite different, I wish not to prove existence of a periodic solution, but existence of this unique a.

Comment: Could you explain that difference? From the unique periodic solution you can take $a=y(0)$ after all. And starting from $a$ you have to show that it is the initial value of a periodic solution.